# Catch PHP file response in AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

The title says it all, i need to validate data and allow user to go to the next step in my modal. I'm sending an AJAX request to a PHP file. How the PHP file should look to return the data?

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $('#reg_btn').on('click', function(){
              $.ajax({
                      type: "POST",
                      url: 'checksubscriber.php',
                      dataType: 'json',
                      data: {
                        email: $('# .email').val(),
                      },
                      success: function(response) {
                        // User has been successfully subscribed
                        // Do something here
                      },
                      error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {

                  }

                    });

                    e.preventDefault();
                    return false;
                });
    </script>
```

Checksubscriber.php

```
        <?php
    require("vendor/autoload.php");

    use \DrewM\MailChimp\MailChimp;
    $mc = new MailChimp('api_key_goes_here'); 

    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $subscriber_hash = $mc->subscriberHash($email);

    $response = [];
    $list_id = 'list_id_goes_here';

    $resp = $mc->get("/lists/$list_id/members/$subscriber_hash";

    if ($mc->success()) {

        // User successfully subscribed - set HTTP status code to 200
        http_response_code(200);
    } else {

        // User not subscribed - set HTTP status code to 400
        http_response_code(400);
    }

    // Return json-formatted response
    echo json_encode($response); 
    ?>
```

HTML + JS of the modal

```
    <button type="submit" onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='block'" > HERE IS MY BUTTON </button>
    <!-- multistep form -->
    <div id="id01" class="modalx modalx-style_set">
    <form id="msform">
    <!-- progressbar -->
    <ul id="progressbar">
    <li class="active">LOG IN</li>
    <li>TERMS</li>
    <li>INFO</li>
    </ul>
    <!-- fieldsets -->
    <fieldset>
    <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email" />
    <input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button" value="Next" />
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
    <input type="text" name="address" placeholder="Complete address" />
    <input type="button" name="previous" class="previous action-button" value="Back" />
    <input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button" value="Next" />
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
    <input type="button" name="previous" class="previous action-button" value="Back" />
    </fieldset>
    </form>

        <script>
//jQuery time
   $(document).ready(function(){
     var modalx = document.getElementById('id01');

     // When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
     window.onclick = function(event) {
         if (event.target == modalx) {
             modalx.style.display = "none";
         }
     }

   var current_fs, next_fs, previous_fs; //fieldsets
   var left, opacity, scale; //fieldset properties which we will animate
   var animating; //flag to prevent quick multi-click glitches

   $(".next").click(function(){
     if(animating) return false;
     animating = true;

     current_fs = $(this).parent();
     next_fs = $(this).parent().next();

     //activate next step on progressbar using the index of next_fs
     $("#progressbar li").eq($("fieldset").index(next_fs)).addClass("active");

     //show the next fieldset
     next_fs.show();
     //hide the current fieldset with style
     current_fs.animate({opacity: 0}, {
       step: function(now, mx) {
         //as the opacity of current_fs reduces to 0 - stored in "now"
         //1. scale current_fs down to 80%
         scale = 1 - (1 - now) * 0.2;
         //2. bring next_fs from the right(50%)
         left = (now * 50)+"%";
         //3. increase opacity of next_fs to 1 as it moves in
         opacity = 1 - now;
         current_fs.css({'transform': 'scale('+scale+')'});
         next_fs.css({'left': left, 'opacity': opacity});
       },
       duration: 800,
       complete: function(){
         current_fs.hide();
         animating = false;
       },
       //this comes from the custom easing plugin
       easing: 'easeInOutBack'
     });
   });
   </script>
```

I need to write something here in order to post this last part of the code. I have mostly code in my question...

Comment: what is your actual question?

Comment: $resp = $mc->get("/lists/$list_id/members/$subscriber_hash"
 on 8th line u missed closing round bracket.

Comment: Thanks for add Vinod.

Comment: @Lugifah you will receive response data in your ajax success function not in php file.

Comment: Hi Cashbee, I'm trying to receive the response data in my ajax success functions as Abdullah Shoaib stated.

Comment: Actually i'm trying to go to check if an email is subscribed and go to the next fieldset in my modal form based on the mailchimp's response, i'm doing it with baby steps :)

Comment: So you ask how to read values from the `response` variable in the .success function of ajax? because to me, the question seems to be `How the PHP file should look to return the data?` which doesnt make sense because your php looks fine (except the error vinod pointed out)

Comment: Yes, and also if my PHP script is coded correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#reg_btn').on('click', function(event){
         $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: 'checksubscriber.php',
           dataType: 'json',
           data: {
             email: $('# .email').val(),
           },
           success: function(response) {
             $('#block1').hide(); //Adds display:none
             $('#block2').show(); //Removes display:none
           },
           error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
             console.log(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown); 
           }
         });
         event.preventDefault();
         return false;
   });
</script>
```

Try to put console.log(response) inside success function. Reload the page and open the browser console before performing any operation. After that click the element.

Now you should be able to see the output of the PHP file response in browser console.

You can the access the message from response object by using **response.message**.

Dot(.) operator can be used to access the params inside JSON object. You can't access it like response['message']. Since you are sending JSON object from PHP file.

Replace your fieldsets with below code

```
<!-- fieldsets -->
<fieldset id="block1">
    <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email" />
    <input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button" value="Next" />
</fieldset>
<fieldset id="block2" style="display:none">
    <input type="text" name="address" placeholder="Complete address" />
    <input type="button" name="previous" class="previous action-button" value="Back" />
    <input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button" value="Next" />
</fieldset>
<fieldset id="block3" style="display:none">
     <input type="button" name="previous" class="previous action-button" value="Back" />
</fieldset>
```

Comment: Thanks for the add. And what do i need to write in my success:function in order to pass to the next fieldset of my modal?

Comment: @Lugifah Add id attribute to all fieldsets. Then add style display:none to the all the fieldsets except first. After AJAX success then you need to hide the current fieldset and show the next fieldset. jQuery show and hide can be used to show and hide the elements respectively.

Comment: Can i have an example applied to my code? Should i look into toggle or maybe a simpler coding? I read something about hide/show but can't find an answer right now.

Comment: I'll give it a try and come back to accept your answer. Thanks

Comment: Uploaded the files on my server but it doesn't process, it goes to the next page normally. Do i need to insert the AJAX scrip call inside the main JS of the modal somehow?

Comment: @Lugifah Check my updated script section with event param in it. Previously event was not initialized. That might caused the form submit.

Comment: Thanks for your effort, anyways i think i'l choose another modal, this one gives me headaches!! However, when i run it locally everything works as expected, after i upload it it just doesn't work! Tried changing the libraries...more problems..don't know what to do next..maybe you can guide me to a better example? BTW, i managed to validate the email directly from my database, without the mailchimp complication.

Comment: I'm so pissed off... spent 2 days just to abandon this little shit. Thx

Answer (score 1):

whatever you return or echo data from your Checksubscriber.php, it will recorded as response. Alert data in response function just like i did in below code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
                $('#reg_btn').on('click', function(){
                  $.ajax({
                          type: "POST",
                          url: 'checksubscriber.php',
                          dataType: 'json',
                          data: {
                            email: $('# .email').val(),
                          },
                          success: function(response) {
                            alert(response); 
                      },
                          error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {

                      }

                        });

                        e.preventDefault();
                        return false;
                    });
        </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

read response values like

```
success: function(response) {
    var msg = response.message;
    // do with msg whatever you want
},
```

And yes, your PHP code looks fine except the syntax error that Vinod pointed out.
using `http_response_code(400);` to let ajax know it wasn't a success is very nice!

edit: replaced `response['message']` with `response.message`

Comment: If everything looks fine what do i need to write in success:function in order to pass user to the next fieldset of my modal? I'm posting my modal JS right now

Comment: Do i need to wrap the fieldset's in divs? Whould be much easier to go to the next step? Or maybe place div inside fieldsets?

Comment: Also, should i insert the AJAX call script inside the main JS of the modal? or can i leave it as it is?